# Strange behaviour of response when it isn't json in angularjs get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I have problem with error in angularjs:

> Error: [$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: 'test string test string'  Parse error: "{}"

So if I understand it correctly, the response from the server hasn't good JSON format. Let's say that I can't change it on the server side and I try to repair it on the frontend.

So I try to use transformResponse:

```
function testFunc() {
    return $http.get('url', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        transformResponse: function(data) 
            return {'status': data} 
        }
    })
}
```

And then, ok, I haven't errors and everything looks fine but I expected in response something like that: `{"status": "test string test string"}`

But instead, I have html code from whole my site (`{"status": '<HTML>....'}`) Why data isn't this string which was when it was the error? How can I deal with it?

Comment: You should really fix the JSON on the server side. If you don't, not only will this be a problem for you now, but will continue to be a problem every time you or anyone else wants to consume that API. The problem gets worse if the malformed JSON payload changes. You have to fix it every single time it changes.

Comment: To bypass the JSON parser use - `transformResponse: angular.identity`. Transforming it to an object with a property named `status` will cause confusion. The $http service returns a response object which also has a property named `status`.

Comment: ok, but the problem is content of response: it's html code instead "test string test string" like when I had error.

Comment: It means your API call was not successful. If the API call is successful, you should see the response in network tab of your browser developer tools. There is an error when the api call was made from the backend. This is not a UI issue but the backend api problem.